# Grails 3 load controller(s) dynamically from jar file(s)

Tags: grails, grails-controller, grails3

Is there any way in Grails 3 to have some controller classes inside a .jar file and dynamically loading it in the main grails application?

What i am trying to achieve is to be able to load and unload dynamically .jar files for different clients of my application (eg. customization is business logic etc.)

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I suppose you could make each set of controllers a plugin and include the custom plugin with each build but man that sounds like a nightmare to manage. Controllers really shouldn't have much business logic in them.

Comment: Hi @todd-sharp and thank you so much for your comment. Actually i was thinking about plugins but if that's the case i will bundle all the business logic per client (along with extra service(s) and controller(s)) in one plugin and deploy it. I had in mind something more dynamic, like manually loading the jars and somehow modify the url mappings in order to reflect the changes controller-wise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way in Grails 3 to have some controller classes inside a
>   .jar file and dynamically loading it in the main grails application?

Yes.

Grails 3 plugins are distributed as normal .jar files.  If you write a plugin that contains any number of controllers then consume that plugin from an application, all of the controllers in the plugin will be dynamically loaded into the grails application from the plugin jar.